# App quits unexpectedly due to usage of NSOperationQueue

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my application, I am uploading multiple files to server. Every upload will take some time that depends on the size of the file. To obtain the faster UI experience while uploading the file , I am using NSOperationQueue.

```
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                    initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(uploadFiles) object:nil];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
```

some times, it causes application to quit unexpectedly. Here is the crash content generated in machine.

```
Crashed Thread:  2  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fe26add8020

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000a4
```

Mostly this crash will occur after multiple uploads (sometimes after 20 uploads/sometimes after 70 uploads). Can anyone provide the solution to accomplish the above issue.

Comment: I see a call to `release` above - I assume you're not using ARC?  Any chance `self` has been released.  (The NSInvocation retains its arguments but if you overrelease it elsewhere, the invocation could cause a crash.)

Comment: Note that Nstimer(Repeated) is running inside the uploadFiles operation.

Comment: Are you invalidating the timer properly?  Maybe post the contents of `uploadFiles`.

Comment: Also, you might just try `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(uploadFiles) withObject:nil]` rather than an operation queue.

Comment: @Jon brooks yes, I am using ARC. And that nstimer will run until the app quits. because it will check any new files available to upload. In this condition , i can't invalidate the nstimer.

Comment: If you're using ARC, then `[operationQueue release]` is incorrect.  I would think it would trigger a compile error.

Comment: @jon Brooks i have removed the compile error by using this -fno-objc-arc in compiler flags(Build phase).

Comment: @jon brooks i have used performSelectorInBackground, it doing the same operation as NSOperationQueue. I didn't find any difference. I will check by doing multiple uploads and post here if any memory leak occurs.